Implementing Modal Login on First Interaction in Flutter
I'm working on a Flutter web/app project and need some guidance on implementing a specific login flow. I want to eliminate the traditional login page. Instead, users should land directly on the homepage and be able to freely explore the content by scrolling up and down without any interruption. The requirement is to prompt users to log in only when they attempt to interact with the content for the first time (like clicking on any element). I plan to show a modal login sheet at this point. Could anyone suggest how to detect the first interactive user action in Flutter and trigger the login modal only then? Any example code or plugins that could help with this behavior would be greatly appreciated.
I'm unable to find a workable solution.
